# Significance of death on Ganesh Chathurthi

Tags: scripture, ganesha, festivals, sraddha, pitru

If one's father expires on the same day as Ganesh Chaturthi, I would like to know if there's a significance attached to one's death on an auspicious day like the Ganesh Chaturthi.

Secondly, as both the father's shraddha and Ganesh vrat on chaturthi are equally important for the well being of a family, how can the family perform both the Ganesh vrat and father's shraddha in the later years?

What do scriptures say about this?

Comment: I think there is no significance of death on Ganesh chaturdi.. But one should not celebrate festivals for at least one year if someone dies from Paternal side.